# Open image in new tab/window without triggering download

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open an image in a new tab using this simple code.

```
window.open(file.url);
```

The file is a .jpg file and my browser is Chrome. Instead of showing the image in a new tab it triggers the download window and asks me to download it to my PC.

Is this a javascript issue? Or is it a default Chrome setting? I have googled this for a while and some people are suggesting it could be a MIME type problem but I have no control over the image coming from the server.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a MIME type problem, yeah. Is it a possibility to open a new page, with an `<img>` element with the image src inside it?

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by **@Lachlan Walls** in the comments, you can open a blank tab and write a simple html with an img tag:

```
const image_window = window.open("", "_blank")
image_window.document.write(`
      <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" alt="Example" height="100%" width="100%">
        </body>
      </html>
`);
```